# ASP.Net MVC 5 Html.DropDownListFor - Model is always nu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

In my Model I have defined the following:

public string Program {get;set;}

public IEnumerable ProgramList...

In my View I have:

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Program, Model.ProgramList);

My problem is that in the view, **Model** is always NULL.  In the examples I've seen, the second parameter for DropDownListFor is either hard-coded values or Enums.

Is what I'm attempting possible?

Why is Model always Null?

Thanks

Comment: What's the definition of ProgramList

Comment: public IEnumerable<SelectionListItem> ProgramList
{
  get
 {
        //retrieves data from the database and coverts to List<SelectListItem>
}
set
{
  ProgramList = value;
}

Comment: 1. How are you passing the model instance to the view? 2. How is it set?

Comment: I'm not explicitly, is that the issue?
@Html.DropDownList(model => model.Program  always works successfully.  How does this reference the instance?

Comment: Sounds like you set Program but not ProgramList.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I worked this out finally, it was due to the way I launched my View